# Controlling multiple switches using voltage

Tags: voltage, switches, laptop, ladder

I want to use my laptop with the lid closed and be able to press its function buttons (including power on/off), i.e. shorting their pins, using a wired "remote control" with the same amount of buttons. In my case there are 6 of them and I was able to open the laptop and solder some cables to the switches' pins so I have access to them externally.

I could use 6+ wires and the necessary switches, but that's precisely what I'm avoiding. I can house a small circuit next to the laptop and connect it to a "remote control" with 6 switches, but I wanted to avoid using 6+ different wires at distance and having the possibility to press multiple buttons at once without causing issues.

I wanted to know if there's any way of controlling them using voltage (less wires needed, ideally 2 or 3) and some opamps and/or transistors. I though of something like a voltage ladder on the remote and have an Arduino and its ADC doing the control, shorting the pins on the laptop, but I was looking for something more "discrete". Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe a 3:8 decoder driving an 8x1:1 analog switch IC or discrete MOSFETs.  Without seeing the schematic, I do not recommend bussing the switches or otherwise connecting their wires together.

Comment: get an external usb keyboard; you can press anything on it and have but 4 wires. you could use a SIPO shift register and an active device on the button end, but you're still looking at 4 wires for that (vcc+gnd,data,clk).

Comment: Get a bluetooth keyboard... Zero wires.

Comment: expanding on what @dandavis said ... you can tear out the electronics from a USB keyboard and replace the keys with 6 switches and put the whole thing into a small enclosure

Comment: I think the keyboard option is a bit overkill. Solution by @vir seems more appropriate, although I may need some kind of debouncing to separate button presses before the decoder